# Schedule a task everyday except on Sunday in Windows task scheduler

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

For scheduling a task weekly(once a week) in windows task scheduler, I am using following code from [codeplex](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/):

```
            TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
            DateTime t = ts.RootFolder.Tasks["Test"].LastRunTime;
            td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

            td.Triggers.Add(new TimeTrigger(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
            //td.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromHours(23);

            td.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger
            {
                StartBoundary = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
                DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Friday
            });


            // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
            td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("D:\\Tasks\\obj\\x86\\Debug\\Tasks.exe", "SPU", null));

            // Register the task in the root folder
            ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);
```

How can I schedule a task which will execute 6 days a week(excluding Sunday)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but `DaysOfTheWeek` is marked with the `Flags` attribute, so you should be able to specify multiple days like this:

```
DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday | DaysOfTheWeek.Tuesday | DaysOfTheWeek.Wednesday
             | DaysOfTheWeek.Thursday | DaysOfTheWeek.Friday | DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday
```